# How can I acess schema from my controller in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, schema

I have a schema as shown below, its a mongoDB native syntax schema, How can I export this Schema to my controller, and how to acess the same in the controller. Should I import something as we does using mongoose, as well how can I name this schema.

```
$jsonSchema: {
        bsonType: "object",
        properties: {

            name: {
                bsonType: "string",
                description: "must be a string"
            },
            teacherId: {
                bsonType: "objectId",
                description: "must be a Object ID"
            }
        }    
    }
```